# Javascript сохрание cookie

Tags: javascript

Разбираю пример из урока, в котором объясняется как с помощью Javascript сохранить и потом использовать cookie, но у меня пример не работает, не могу разобраться почему, подскажите.

```
<body onload="z()">
    Имя <input type="text" id="namecom" /><br />
    Email <input type="text" id="email" /><br />
    Сайт <input type="text" id="site" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="f()"/>
</body>
```

Cкрипт

```
   <script>
    function f() {
        var namecom = document.getElementById("namecom");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var site = document.getElementById("site");

        document.cookie = "namecom=" + encodeURIComponent(namecom.value) + ";max-age=" + 315360000 + ";path=/";
        document.cookie = "email=" + encodeURIComponent(email.value) + ";max-age=" + 315360000 + ";path=/";
        document.cookie = "site=" + encodeURIComponent(email.site) + ";max-age=" + 315360000 + ";path=/";
    }

    function opencookie(par){
        var allcookies = document.cookie;
        var pos = allcookies.indexOf(par);
        var len = par.length;
        if (pos !== -1) {
            var start = pos + len + 1;
            var end = allcookies.indexOf(';', start);

            if (end == -1)
            end = allcookies.length;

            var value = allcookies.substring(start, end);
            value = decodeURIConponent(value);
            this.cook = value;
        }
    }

    function z(){
        alert('Содержимое cookies' + document.cookie);
        if(document.cookie !== ''){
            var namecomcook = new opencookie('namecom');
            alert(nameconcook.cook);
            var emailcook = new opencookie('emeil');
            alert(emailcook.cook);
            var sitecook = new opencookie('site');
            alert(sitecook.cook);

            var namecom = document.getElementById("namecom");
            var email = document.getElementById("email");
            var site = document.getElementById("site");

            namecom.value = namecomcook.cook;
            email.value = emailcook.cook;
            site.value = sitecook.cook;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Код http://jsfiddle.net/XZ2ff/3/

Comment: Не вижу полного кода. Функция `opencookie()` ничего не возвращает.

Comment: Это весь код, который был в примере, несколько раз проверено.
   
При этом в разных браузерах: в ие9 скрипт срабатывает, но ругается на функцию decodeURIConponent, в фф из функции z() выводится только первый алерт   alert('Содержимое cookies ' + document.cookie); в хроме скрипт не работает.

Comment: а может все-таки `jQuery` использовать? Там такой плагин хороший есть.

Comment: @Maris а что за плагин?

Comment: напр. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie, как использовать написано.

Comment: >Не вижу полного кода. Функция opencookie() ничего не возвращает.

@lampa - она и не должна ни чего возвращать это "класс" (там же `new` и this...)

Comment: @Rules да я тогда же и понял, что тупанул :)

Answer (score 3):

У вас море синтаксических ошибок, особенно из-за невнимательности :)

Обновил, переоформил:

```
function f() {
    var namecom = document.getElementById("namecom");
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var site = document.getElementById("site");
    var max_age = 315360000;

    document.cookie = "namecom=" + namecom.value + ";max-age=" + max_age + ";path=/";
    document.cookie = "email=" + email.value + ";max-age=" + max_age + ";path=/";
    document.cookie = "site=" + email.value + ";max-age=" + max_age + ";path=/";

}

function opencookie(par){
    var allcookies = document.cookie;
    var pos = allcookies.indexOf(par);

console.log(allcookies);
console.log(par);
console.log(pos);
console.log('----------');

    var len = par.length;

    if (pos !== -1) {
        var start = pos + len + 1;
        var end = allcookies.indexOf(';', start);

        if (end == -1) end = allcookies.length;

        var value = allcookies.substring(start, end);

        return !value ? false : value;
    }
}

function z(){

    if(document.cookie){

        var namecomcook = opencookie('namecom');
        alert(namecomcook);

        var emailcook = opencookie('email');
        alert(emailcook);

        var sitecook = opencookie('site');
        alert(sitecook);

        var namecom = document.getElementById("namecom");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var site = document.getElementById("site");

        namecom.value = namecomcook;
        email.value = emailcook;
        site.value = sitecook;
    }
}
```